# Synchronize data with skydrive from my application using Live account

Tags: windows-phone-8, authorization, onedrive

My WP8 application must synchronize some data with SkyDrive. Can i use Live account to login into skydrive without popup window with skydrive authorization ?

Answer (score 0):

No.

It is not possible to automatically connect to a users skydrive account without them logging in to it via the appropriate UI.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, but you need to show UI at the access authorization step. All other launches can be done without UI with use InitializeAsync and LoginAsync functions in LiveSdk.